# Selecting a single record with Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to retrieve a single row from a table. This row contains filed that hold foreign keys into another table, which in turns is related to yet another table. I am trying to get just one row returned, yet, the problem is, it returns not only the row but ALL the objects that are jointly related to that table as well. As I have to deal with a fairly large amount of data, the returned object is very cumbersome as it contains all the related data as well. In some cases my script simply times out because there is just far too much data to grab.

My question is; is there a way to retrieve just a single record without the associated fluff with it? I am basically accessing the table via the entityManager from the repository, then trying to get my record by using the ->find($id) method.

I am sure this is something stupidly simple but I can't seem to figure this out. Thanks in advance for any help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2 use "lazy loading", it means that the associated objects are not really retrieved from the database while you don't try to access them.

So the `find($id)` is just fine.